# jsqmessagesviewcontroller бесконечный скролл

Tags: ios, cocoa

Вес привет, никак не могу найти реализацию бесконечного скролла для библиотеки jsqmessagesviewcontroller. Я пытался делать так: программно переворачиваю таблицу на 180 градусов, а так же ячейки. Но сталкивался с проблемой на iphone 6, что не все ячейки переворачиваются, хотя на 5 все ок.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй достучаться до collectionView с сообщениями. Тогда сможешь обрабатывать методы collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath: (предпочтительно, это из UICollectionViewDelegate), а также методы UIScrollViewDelegate.
И когда пользователь доскролит до низу или до последней ячейки - добавляй новые сообщения.

PS: возможно, прийдется написать/дописать делегат для jsqmessagesviewcontroller